Azure log API doesn't retrieve all log ids
I got an Azure function app which is triggered via a pipeline step. I want to display messages on the console to the user during the function's operation and for that I'm using the Append content to log API.
In order to use this API, I need to first retrieve the pipeline's log id using the retrieve log api (https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$projectId/_apis/distributedtask/hubs/$hubName/plans/$planId/logs?api-version=7.1) with the task instance id.
My function app's code has some code at the start, including logging using the APIs shown earlier, opening a new thread in which more logging happens, and the main thread returns immediately.
The problem is that during the run of the main thread which handles the initial request, the list of logs retrieved do not include the one corresponding to my task instance id. Only when logging in the new thread it returns and then I can use it. I'm not sure if the problem occurs because there should be some delay, or if its because there is still no log exists until the main thread returns with a response before the calls to log are invoked in the new thread?
_logId = GetLogId(_taskInstanceId); // here I get null 
LogToPipeline("message"); // this is not shown in the pipeline
Task.Run(() => 
{
  _logId = GetLogId(_taskInstanceId); // here I get the correct one
   LogToPipeline("another message"); //This one IS shown in the pipeline's console
   ... 
}
return "Starting";

Why is this happening?

May be irrelevant but I would like to ask you that your function app is which pricing model - Consumption or Premium or any other App Service Plan? @CodeMonkey

@VivekAnandChakravarthy Premium
